# How to register glut32.dll without regsvr32?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opengl, dll, windows-8

Please tell me how to register glut32.dll without regsvr32 because I have tried everything to register .DLL but it din't work.

Is this a case that I am using Windows 8 **64-bit**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to register glut32.dll. Just put it in near your exe file.

Comment: It worked, I didn't even think of that.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

put 32bit file in syswow64, and 64bit in system32. Your program may find it without regsvr32

Comment: Not sure if this is better than putting it near the .exe. Latter allows easier distribution.